# What information is needed within an XMP tag value?

Tags: gimp, metadata, exiftool

I'm adding XMP metadata to a large number of TIFF files. Initially I was doing this with GIMP, but upon searching for a more efficient way to edit the metadata I found [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/). Looking at the tags with ExifTool shows extra information that GIMP didn't show, and I'd like to know if this information needs to be included or not.

Namely, I'm editing the `Creator`, `Description`, and `CaptionWriter` tags. When I do this in GIMP and view the results with another program like Gwenview or ExifTool, there's extra information added in the `Description` and `Creator` tag values. For example, if I enter data as shown below:

[image: Entering "John Smith" as the Author, "This is Pete the dog." as the Description, and "Myself" as the Description Writer in GIMP]

then open the picture in another program, the tag values are:

```
Caption Writer: Myself
Creator: type="Seq" John Smith
Description: lang="x-default" This is Pete the dog.
```

However, if I edit tags with ExifTool, the `type="Seq"` and `lang="x-default"` are not inserted. Are these necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not necessary.  Exiftool is the gold standard for image metadata.  If it doesn't write something extra, then it isn't needed.

As an example, try writing with exiftool something like:
`exiftool -descrition="default" -description-alt-FR="french description"`
In this case, since there are alternative languages, `x-default` does get written because there are alternative listings in the embedded xmp
`<dc:description>
   <rdf:Alt>
    <rdf:li xml:lang='x-default'>default</rdf:li>
    <rdf:li xml:lang='alt-FR'>french description</rdf:li>
   </rdf:Alt>
  </dc:description>`

In the case of `Creator`, that is a list type tag which means there can be multiple entries.  If you use exiftool to add multiple creators,
`exiftool -Creator=John -Creator=Jane FILE.jpg`
I'm guessing that you will get the `type="Seq"` as well.